# Can't load weights-yolo weight

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to load pretrained yolo weights in a .weights file with pytorch . I entire the whole path way to .weight file but across an error.

```
model = load_model(weights='C:/Users/.../yolov2-tiny-voc_2.weights') 
print(model)
```

---

```
UnpicklingError                           Traceback (most recent call last)

UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\x00'.
```

Comment: Pytorch internally uses Pickle for loading and saving models which might have some cross-platform (OS) compatibility issues. My guess is that you are trying to load  a model saved on Linux OS in WIndows OS. Instead of torch.load you can directly use pickle.load. Make sure that you open the file in binary format for using pickle.load.